# P-values too low to plot

Tags: r, p-value, gwas

In my GWAS analysis, I got some very low p-values (I have a very large dataset), below E-600. R Studio is not able to plot the values below E-300.
Do you have any suggestions on how to plot these, and if there is some software that could do it?

Comment: Hi @A29, welcome to CV. E-600 is effectively 0. So you might as well set them to zero to plot them.

Comment: I think it’d be a challenge to show that anyone’s understanding of a topic will be furthered by knowing whether p is E-30 or E-300.

Comment: Better than p-values might be the use of so-called "S-values," which are the (binary) logarithms of the p-values.  It's unclear how R Studio might be used to plot anything (presumably you refer to `R` or an addon graphics package) and even less clear why it might fail to plot tiny values: please provide some details so we can understand what's going wrong and what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Library `gap` has a function [`mhtplot.trunc`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gap/html/mhtplot.trunc.html) that seems to be made for extremely low p values.

> The rationale of this function is to extend mhtplot() to handle extremely small p values as often seen from a protein GWAS. Optionally, the function also draws an ordinary Manhattan plot.